# Regarding the thermal properties of a substance

Tags: solid-state-physics, thermal-conductivity

Let us suppose that on object( a metal preferably) is heated. Let us also suppose that it is homogeneous. My assumption is that the individual atoms will start oscillating about their mean position in a simple harmonic motion with some angular frequency(which will be a function of the temperature) and amplitude $A$.

The question is on what factors of will  the amplitude $A$ depend upon. My best guess is that it will be inversely proportional to the density.If possible provide an equation which relates the amplitude of the oscillation and the properties of the substance.

Comment: I think amplitude needs to be somehow proportional to temperature. One can roughly think that when the amplitude of oscillation exceeds the bond length the solid melts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is the so called *Debye model*, which is the 3D version of Einstein's model. It describes the body as being composed of springs. So your only free parameter is the spring constant $k$. This should be connected to the elasticity of the material.

Comment: Interesting. I've looked this up on wikipedia, however the article  has made no mention of the amplitude of the oscillation. Can you further elaborate on how the maximum amplitude will depend on the elasticity.

Comment: Well, if you have a spring with spring constant $k$ the potential energy is $E_{pot} = \frac{1}{2}k x^2$, if we take a 1D model. So the amplitude in $x$-direction is $A_x =x$. Furthermore, if you use the equipartition theorem you conclude, that on average the potential energy will be $\frac{1}{2}k_B T$ (per degree of freedom). Therefore, $A_x = ...$. And the total amplitude will be $|\vec A| = \sqrt{A_x^2 + A_y^2 + A_z^2}$. The spring constant will be some function of the elasticity -- this is an approximation, however, I guess a rather good one.